# When does MongoDB Fetch results in java driver

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-java

```
MongoClient mc=new MongoClient();
MongoDatabase mdb=mc.getDatabase("testdb");
MongoCollection mcol=mdb.getCollection("testcol");
FindIterable<Document> fi=mcol.find();

MongoCursor<Document> mcur=fi.iterator();
MongoCursor<Document> mcur2=fi.iterator();
```

will mcur and mcur2 have same results all the time as they are reference of FindIterable fi.

In which step of the above code mongodb will get the results Inside mongoCursor or FindIterable step?

Answer (score 0):

`mcol.find()` is the point where the results are obtained, the `.find()` will pull all documents from the collection `"testcol"`.

You don't necessarily need to use a `FindIterable` object an ordinary `List<BasicDBObject>` does work.

then you can iterate through using:

```
 for(DBObject obj : objList) {
     //perform operations
     String name = (String) obj.get("nameOfField");
 }
```

hope this helps.